# Spark DataFrame: Computing row-wise mean (or any aggregate operation)

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a Spark DataFrame loaded up in memory, and I want to take the mean (or any aggregate operation) over the columns. How would I do that? (In `numpy`, this is known as taking an operation over `axis=1`).

If one were calculating the mean of the DataFrame down the rows (`axis=0`), then this is already built in:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
F.mean(...)
```

But is there a way to programmatically do this against the entries in the columns? For example, from the DataFrame below

```
+--+--+---+---+
|id|US| UK|Can|
+--+--+---+---+
| 1|50|  0|  0|
| 1| 0|100|  0|
| 1| 0|  0|125|
| 2|75|  0|  0|
+--+--+---+---+
```

Omitting `id`, the means would be

```
+------+
|  mean|
+------+
| 16.66|
| 33.33|
| 41.67|
| 25.00|
+------+
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All you need here is a standard SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT (US + UK + CAN) / 3 AS mean FROM df
```

which can be used directly with `SqlContext.sql` or expressed using DSL

```py
df.select(((col("UK") + col("US") + col("CAN")) / lit(3)).alias("mean"))
```

If you have a larger number of columns you can generate expression as follows:

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

n = lit(len(df.columns) - 1.0)
rowMean  = (reduce(add, (col(x) for x in df.columns[1:])) / n).alias("mean")

df.select(rowMean)
```

or

```
rowMean  = (sum(col(x) for x in df.columns[1:]) / n).alias("mean")
df.select(rowMean)
```

Finally its equivalent in Scala:

```scala
df.select(df.columns
  .drop(1)
  .map(col)
  .reduce(_ + _)
  .divide(df.columns.size - 1)
  .alias("mean"))
```

In a more complex scenario you can combine columns using `array` function and use an UDF to compute statistics:

```py
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

combined = array(*(col(x) for x in df.columns[1:]))
median_udf = udf(lambda xs: float(np.median(xs)), FloatType())

df.select(median_udf(combined).alias("median"))
```

The same operation expressed using Scala API:

```scala
val combined = array(df.columns.drop(1).map(col).map(_.cast(DoubleType)): _*)
val median_udf = udf((xs: Seq[Double]) => 
    breeze.stats.DescriptiveStats.percentile(xs, 0.5))

df.select(median_udf(combined).alias("median"))
```

Since **Spark 2.4** an alternative approach is to combine values into an array and apply `aggregate` expression. See for example [Spark Scala row-wise average by handling null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53189965/6910411).

Comment: Where does `reduce` come from in your beginning example?

Comment: from functools import reduce

Answer (score 1):

in Scala something like this would do it

```
val cols = Seq("US","UK","Can")
f.map(r => (r.getAs[Int]("id"),r.getValuesMap(cols).values.fold(0.0)(_+_)/cols.length)).toDF
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if you initially didn't have a DataFrame though?

Comment: no r would get the dataframe row and getValueMap extracts a Map with k = column; value = the column's value and then values returns an iterable with the values the fold sums them. The whole thing returns a tuple int,float which can be turned back to a dataframe