# Total zero count across all columns in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I need to find the percentage of zero across all columns in a pyspark dataframe. How to find the count of zero across each columns in the dataframe?

P.S: I have tried converting the dataframe into a pandas dataframe and used value_counts. But inferring it's observation is not possible for a large dataset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Spark DataFrame: Computing row-wise mean (or any aggregate operation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670958/spark-dataframe-computing-row-wise-mean-or-any-aggregate-operation) and [Apply a transformation to multiple columns pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452076/apply-a-transformation-to-multiple-columns-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 6):

"How to find the count of zero across each columns in the dataframe?"

First:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df_zero = df.select([F.count(F.when(df[c] == 0, c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
```

Second: you can then see the count (compared to .show(), this gives you better view. And the speed is not much different):

```
df_zero.limit(2).toPandas().head()
```

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to find number of `0` in a column of a table.

Just replace `Tablename` and `"column name"` with the appropriate values:

```py
Tablename.filter(col("column name")==0).count()
```