# pyspark calculate mean of all columns in one line

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, mean

I would like  to calculate the mean value of each column without specifying all the columns name.

So for example instead of doing:

```
res = df.select([mean('col1'), mean('col2')])
```

I would like to do something equivalent to:

```
res = df.select([mean('*')])
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply a transformation to multiple columns pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452076/apply-a-transformation-to-multiple-columns-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: `df.select(*[mean(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])`

Comment: Thanks @pault. I am not sure it is a complete duplicate but maybe you can see better than me :)

Comment: the general concept of apply a function to every column using a list comprehension is duplicated. I'll see if I can find time to update the linked Q&A to be more generic.

Comment: Maybe a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/sparksql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-column

Comment: Pault - why do we have to add * before []?

Comment: @cph_sto that is to unpack the list to pass in each column expression as an argument.

Comment: @pault completely understood. Thanks 

Answer (score 6):

similar solution but maybe a little easier to read:

```
results= df.agg(*(avg(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns))
```

to easily retrieve the information use:

```
results.first().asDict()
```

it will be handy when you use it to fill NaN like:

```
df.na.fill(results.first().asDict())
```

no promotion just gratitude from my side: I picked that cool trick up in a wonderfull pyspark-class by Layla AI (Pyspark Essentials for Data Scientists)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by

```py
res  = df.select(*[f.mean(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
```