# How to translate PySpark res = notesCollege.select(*[f.mean(c).alias(c) for c in notesCollege.columns]) into Java Spark?

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to apply a PySpark statement suggested in
[pyspark calculate mean of all columns in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855300/pyspark-calculate-mean-of-all-columns-in-one-line) question, into my Java program but I don't know how.

In the next codes, `notesCollege` is a  `Dataset` / `Dataframe`:

```
+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+
|ORTH|GRAM|EXPR|RECI1|MATH|ANGL|HIST|BIOL|EDNU|ARTS|TECH|EPS |RECI2|EXPO|
+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+
|13.0|10.0|2.0 |4.0  |9.0 |9.0 |8.0 |7.0 |7.5 |1.5 |14.0|10.0|10.5 |13.0|
|6.5 |8.0 |8.5 |14.0 |13.0|7.0 |11.0|8.5 |16.0|4.0 |18.0|18.0|16.0 |15.0|
|14.0|6.5 |8.0 |5.0  |11.0|8.0 |9.5 |8.0 |18.5|9.5 |14.0|16.5|14.0 |13.0|
|13.0|7.5 |9.0 |5.0  |10.0|10.5|10.0|16.0|16.0|11.5|0.0 |11.5|15.0 |18.0|
|15.0|7.5 |10.0|14.0 |12.0|11.0|9.0 |11.0|16.5|13.5|16.0|13.0|15.51|17.0|
|5.0 |8.0 |5.5 |6.5  |16.0|12.0|9.0 |7.0 |13.5|5.0 |16.0|12.5|13.0 |17.5|
|12.0|6.5 |9.0 |16.0 |18.0|13.5|9.0 |10.0|15.0|11.0|16.0|13.5|14.0 |18.0|
|8.5 |2.5 |9.0 |13.0 |12.0|9.5 |12.0|13.5|16.5|8.0 |13.0|12.0|14.0 |17.0|
|15.5|7.5 |12.5|16.0 |15.0|13.0|12.0|13.5|17.0|14.0|15.0|16.0|15.0 |17.0|
|20.0|14.5|16.5|10.5 |18.0|16.5|15.0|10.5|18.0|13.5|12.0|14.5|13.0 |15.0|
|6.0 |4.0 |11.0|9.5  |13.0|12.0|11.0|7.5 |17.5|12.0|18.0|13.5|13.0 |17.0|
|0.0 |5.5 |6.0 |6.0  |9.0 |3.0 |7.0 |2.0 |12.0|1.5 |15.0|12.5|14.0 |0.0 |
|15.5|12.0|12.0|8.0  |17.0|17.0|11.0|4.5 |16.0|9.0 |13.0|5.0 |12.5 |16.5|
|15.0|6.5 |11.5|10.0 |13.0|12.5|7.0 |11.0|14.0|7.0 |14.0|11.0|15.0 |13.0|
|11.0|9.0 |7.5 |11.0 |12.5|11.0|9.0 |11.5|18.0|8.5 |17.0|15.0|15.0 |15.0|
|6.5 |9.0 |10.0|10.0 |10.0|6.5 |7.0 |12.5|18.0|14.5|16.0|13.5|13.0 |18.0|
|7.0 |4.5 |6.0 |6.0  |15.0|13.5|11.0|7.0 |7.0 |6.5 |11.0|10.5|13.5 |16.0|
|11.5|8.5 |7.5 |12.0 |10.0|7.5 |8.0 |10.0|17.5|7.0 |11.0|16.5|15.5 |14.0|
|4.5 |7.5 |9.0 |12.0 |12.0|9.0 |7.0 |11.5|17.0|12.5|12.0|16.0|13.0 |18.0|
|5.5 |8.0 |8.0 |11.0 |10.0|12.0|8.0 |7.0 |12.0|5.0 |18.0|10.5|13.0 |15.0|
|16.0|13.5|14.5|9.5  |16.0|17.0|11.5|12.5|19.0|13.5|6.0 |11.0|16.0 |16.0|
|5.5 |2.0 |7.5 |14.5 |11.0|10.0|7.0 |8.0 |15.5|8.0 |16.0|13.5|13.0 |15.0|
|14.0|8.0 |6.5 |6.5  |10.0|14.5|9.0 |5.0 |9.5 |3.5 |0.0 |18.5|13.0 |0.0 |
|5.5 |8.0 |4.5 |15.0 |8.0 |7.5 |5.0 |5.0 |13.5|8.0 |6.0 |9.0 |0.0  |13.0|
|11.0|4.0 |10.5|6.0  |11.0|12.0|9.0 |17.0|14.0|12.5|8.0 |10.5|17.5 |15.0|
|4.5 |7.0 |10.5|11.5 |14.0|8.5 |7.5 |7.0 |18.0|14.0|13.0|15.5|18.0 |13.0|
|9.0 |8.5 |7.5 |10.0 |14.0|11.5|9.0 |15.0|17.5|9.0 |13.0|13.5|17.5 |16.0|
+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+----+

or as csv:
ORTH,GRAM,EXPR,RECI1,MATH,ANGL,HIST,BIOL,EDNU,ARTS,TECH,EPS,RECI2,EXPO
13.00,10.00,2.00,4.00,9.00,9.00,8.00,7.00,7.50,1.50,14.00,10.00,10.50,13.00
6.50,8.00,8.50,14.00,13.00,7.00,11.00,8.50,16.00,4.00,18.00,18.00,16.00,15.00
14.00,6.50,8.00,5.00,11.00,8.00,9.50,8.00,18.50,9.50,14.00,16.50,14.00,13.00
13.00,7.50,9.00,5.00,10.00,10.50,10.00,16.00,16.00,11.50,0.00,11.50,15.00,18.00
15.00,7.50,10.00,14.00,12.00,11.00,9.00,11.00,16.50,13.50,16.00,13.00,15.51,17.00
5.00,8.00,5.50,6.50,16.00,12.00,9.00,7.00,13.50,5.00,16.00,12.50,13.00,17.50
12.00,6.50,9.00,16.00,18.00,13.50,9.00,10.00,15.00,11.00,16.00,13.50,14.00,18.00
8.50,2.50,9.00,13.00,12.00,9.50,12.00,13.50,16.50,8.00,13.00,12.00,14.00,17.00
15.50,7.50,12.50,16.00,15.00,13.00,12.00,13.50,17.00,14.00,15.00,16.00,15.00,17.00
20.00,14.50,16.50,10.50,18.00,16.50,15.00,10.50,18.00,13.50,12.00,14.50,13.00,15.00
6.00,4.00,11.00,9.50,13.00,12.00,11.00,7.50,17.50,12.00,18.00,13.50,13.00,17.00
0.00,5.50,6.00,6.00,9.00,3.00,7.00,2.00,12.00,1.50,15.00,12.50,14.00,0.00
15.50,12.00,12.00,8.00,17.00,17.00,11.00,4.50,16.00,9.00,13.00,5.00,12.50,16.50
15.00,6.50,11.50,10.00,13.00,12.50,7.00,11.00,14.00,7.00,14.00,11.00,15.00,13.00
11.00,9.00,7.50,11.00,12.50,11.00,9.00,11.50,18.00,8.50,17.00,15.00,15.00,15.00
6.50,9.00,10.00,10.00,10.00,6.50,7.00,12.50,18.00,14.50,16.00,13.50,13.00,18.00
7.00,4.50,6.00,6.00,15.00,13.50,11.00,7.00,7.00,6.50,11.00,10.50,13.50,16.00
11.50,8.50,7.50,12.00,10.00,7.50,8.00,10.00,17.50,7.00,11.00,16.50,15.50,14.00
4.50,7.50,9.00,12.00,12.00,9.00,7.00,11.50,17.00,12.50,12.00,16.00,13.00,18.00
5.50,8.00,8.00,11.00,10.00,12.00,8.00,7.00,12.00,5.00,18.00,10.50,13.00,15.00
16.00,13.50,14.50,9.50,16.00,17.00,11.50,12.50,19.00,13.50,6.00,11.00,16.00,16.00
5.50,2.00,7.50,14.50,11.00,10.00,7.00,8.00,15.50,8.00,16.00,13.50,13.00,15.00
14.00,8.00,6.50,6.50,10.00,14.50,9.00,5.00,9.50,3.50,0.00,18.50,13.00,0.00
5.50,8.00,4.50,15.00,8.00,7.50,5.00,5.00,13.50,8.00,6.00,9.00,0.00,13.00
11.00,4.00,10.50,6.00,11.00,12.00,9.00,17.00,14.00,12.50,8.00,10.50,17.50,15.00
4.50,7.00,10.50,11.50,14.00,8.50,7.50,7.00,18.00,14.00,13.00,15.50,18.00,13.00
9.00,8.50,7.50,10.00,14.00,11.50,9.00,15.00,17.50,9.00,13.00,13.50,17.50,16.00
```

Here's the Python code I would like to translate:

```py
# f imports org.apache.spark.sql.functions
res  = notesCollege.select(*[f.mean(c).alias(c) for c in notesCollege.columns])
```

that calculates means for each of its columns.

Starting with this expression,
it looks like I should replace the `*` inside by some kind of lambda (?),
but I don't see how.

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

Dataset<Row> res = notesCollege.select(*[mean(c).alias(c) for c in notesCollege.columns()])
```

How to make this select statement work with Java too?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I succeed with these statements:

```java
List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();

for(String fieldName : notesCollege.columns()) {
   Column field = round(mean(new Column(fieldName)), 3)
      .as(String.format("mean_%s", fieldName));

   columns.add(field);
}

Dataset<Row> moyennes = notesCollege.select(columns.toArray(new Column[]{}));
moyennes.show();
```

They are working:

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+----------+---------+
|mean_ORTH|mean_GRAM|mean_EXPR|mean_RECI1|mean_MATH|mean_ANGL|mean_HIST|mean_BIOL|mean_EDNU|mean_ARTS|mean_TECH|mean_EPS|mean_RECI2|mean_EXPO|
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+----------+---------+
|   10.019|    7.556|    8.889|    10.093|   12.574|   10.926|    9.204|    9.593|   15.204|    9.019|    12.63|  13.074|    13.797|   14.481|
+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+----------+---------+
```

---

To loose less statements for later use, I can also write this, less clumsy:

```java
Function<String, Column> mean = field -> round(mean(new Column(field)), 3);
Dataset<Row> moyennes = onAllFields(notesCollege, mean, "mean_%s");
moyennes.show(nombreVariables, 0, true);

Function<String, Column> stdPop = field -> round(stddev_pop(new Column(field)), 4);
Dataset<Row> ecartsTypes = onAllFields(notesCollege, stdPop, "std_%s");
ecartsTypes.show(nombreVariables, 0, true);

private Dataset<Row> onAllFields(Dataset<Row> ds, Function<String, Column> fcn, String destFieldPatternName) {
   List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();

   for(String fieldName : ds.columns()) {
      columns.add(fcn.apply(fieldName)
         .as(String.format(destFieldPatternName, fieldName)));
   }

   return ds.select(columns.toArray(new Column[]{}));
}
```

or

```java
onAllFields(notesCollege, f -> round(mean(new Column(f)), 3), "mean_%s");
onAllFields(notesCollege, f -> round(stddev_pop(new Column(f)), 4), "std_%s");
```

for their concise forms.

---

Whatever, users of Python have a better trick to do so, and I'd like to transpose it.