# How can I calculate mean of columns row wise in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, mean, rowwise

I have a data frame of 4 numerical columns and I have to calculate mean of those columns and store the mean in another column in pyspark.

```
df["mean"] = df.loc[:,d_cols].apply(np.mean, axis=1) (python pandas)
```

I have to do the same thing as above but in pyspark.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. To help others answer your question, please consider editing it to add a minimum reproducible example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670958/spark-dataframe-computing-row-wise-mean-or-any-aggregate-operation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark DataFrame: Computing row-wise mean (or any aggregate operation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670958/spark-dataframe-computing-row-wise-mean-or-any-aggregate-operation)