# row wise calculation on Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32672278/466056) 
I need to do some row wise calculation

```
result= (reduce(add, (<some row wise calculation on col(x)> for x in df.columns[1:])) / n).alias("result")
```

but before that I need to sort the row values  by descending order(change column order in dataframe for each row?)
Suppose I have the following rows

```
 3,7,21,9
 5,15,10,2
```

I need to know rank(order) of each value for each row for example and then calculate sum(value/index)
For first row

```
21 ->4,9->3,7->3,3->1,sum(21/4,9/3,7/3,3/1)
```

For second row

```
15->4,10->3,5->2,2->1,sum(15/4,10/4,5/2,2/1)
```

Not A duplicate as I need the sorting not column wise but row wise

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini But I need it not according to Column name but according to each row

Comment: why you need a sort when you want is average and aggregation? it would be more clear if you include sample input data and expected output

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Nothing in my question implies I need average though I do need aggregation.I need to do some row wise calculation  and then agregation

Comment: I don't know what it means to sort according to each row. As Ramesh suggested, please give an example

Comment: @Yakov you didn't answer the second part of my comment

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I will just a sec

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I hope now Its more clear

Comment: @Yakov, to make your work a bit easy I have tried asnwering below :)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Its not a duplicate as I showed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input dataframe is as below

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|3   |7   |21  |9   |
|5   |15  |10  |2   |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Then you can write a udf function to get your desired output column as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
def sortAndIndex(list):
    return sorted([(value, index+1) for index, value in enumerate(sorted(list))],  reverse=True)

sortAndIndexUdf = f.udf(sortAndIndex, t.ArrayType(t.StructType([t.StructField('key', t.IntegerType(), True), t.StructField('value', t.IntegerType(), True)])))

df.withColumn('sortedAndIndexed', sortAndIndexUdf(f.array([x for x in df.columns])))
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|sortedAndIndexed                  |
+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------+
|3   |7   |21  |9   |[[21, 4], [9, 3], [7, 2], [3, 1]] |
|5   |15  |10  |2   |[[15, 4], [10, 3], [5, 2], [2, 1]]|
+----+----+----+----+----------------------------------+
```

**Update**

You commented as

> my calculation should be sum(value/index) so probably using yours udf funcrtion I should return some kind of reduce(add,)?

for that you can do

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
def divideAndSum(list):
    return sum([float(value)/(index+1) for index, value in enumerate(sorted(list))])

divideAndSumUdf = f.udf(divideAndSum, t.DoubleType())

df.withColumn('divideAndSum', divideAndSumUdf(f.array([x for x in df.columns])))
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+----+----+------------------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|divideAndSum      |
+----+----+----+----+------------------+
|3   |7   |21  |9   |14.75             |
|5   |15  |10  |2   |11.583333333333334|
+----+----+----+----+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks but suppose my calculation should be sum(value/index) so probably using yours udf funcrtion I should return some kind of reduce(add,)?

Comment: at last, it turned out to be aggregation any way. ;) yes you are right

Comment: Could you please update you answer

Comment: @Yakov, I have updated the answer

Comment: Does array is really needed in your second answer?

Comment: Yes its needed for sorting and indexing