# Is there a way to count non-null values per row in a spark df?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very wide df with a large number of columns. I need to get the count of non-null values per row for this in python.

Example DF -

```
+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| name|      date|col01|col02|col03|col04|col05|col06|
+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|name1|2017-12-01|100.0|255.5|333.3| null|125.2|132.7|
|name2|2017-12-01|101.1|105.5| null| null|127.5| null|
```

I want to add a column with a count of non-null values in col01-col06 -

```
+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| name|      date|col01|col02|col03|col04|col05|col06|count|
+-----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|name1|2017-12-01|100.0|255.5|333.3| null|125.2|132.7|    5| 
|name2|2017-12-01|101.1|105.5| null| null|127.5| null|    3|
```

I was able to get this in a pandas df like this -

```
df['count']=df.loc[:,'col01':'col06'].notnull().sum(axis=1)
```

But no luck with spark df so far :( Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark DataFrame: Computing row-wise mean (or any aggregate operation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670958/spark-dataframe-computing-row-wise-mean-or-any-aggregate-operation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert the `null` values to `true`/`false`, then to integers, then sum them:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, None, None, 0], 
                            [2, 3, 4, None], 
                            [None, None, None, None], 
                            [1, 5, 7, 2]], 'a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int')

df.select(sum([F.isnull(df[col]).cast(IntegerType()) for col in df.columns]).alias('null_count')).show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+
|null_count|
+----------+
|         2|
|         1|
|         4|
|         0|
+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much gmds! This is exactly what I was looking for. I made a slight update to this to subtract this number from the total count (as I wanted the non-null count) and used withColumn to add the new column and that was it :)

Comment: @user11308481 no problem! (I didn't see you wanted the *non* null count; my bad)

Comment: @gmds I get the error that "TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable", any suggestions?